# Android Studio - Run application with coverage

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am trying to run the application with coverage however the run with coverage *button is disabled* .

Here is how it looks - 
[image]

How to enable this ?

Thanks .

Comment: I was able to get the coverage with ./gradlew createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

Command Line -

```
createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport
```

You can get the coverage report at -

```
{project}/build/reports/coverage/index.html
```